# Postgres not creating tables properly with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

I've setup my hibernate app to use the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users
spring.datasource.username=james
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.database: MySql
spring.jpa.database =  postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I've also created a postgres database ***users***, but when I run my application, it throws all these unsuccessful alter table errors?!

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists user cascade
2016-06-23 10:46:05.406 ERROR 3364 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
2016-06-23 10:46:05.407 ERROR 3364 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 22

Hibernate: alter table user_credential drop constraint FK_14ncv1m0gqncrbiagrs4uaqo8
2016-06-23 10:36:36.199 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_credential drop constraint FK_14ncv1m0gqncrbiagrs4uaqo8
2016-06-23 10:36:36.199 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "user_credential" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK_5q4rc4fh1on6567qk69uesvyf
2016-06-23 10:36:36.200 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK_5q4rc4fh1on6567qk69uesvyf
2016-06-23 10:36:36.200 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "user_roles" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK_g1uebn6mqk9qiaw45vnacmyo2
2016-06-23 10:36:36.200 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK_g1uebn6mqk9qiaw45vnacmyo2
2016-06-23 10:36:36.200 ERROR 3235 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "user_roles" does not exist
```

Everything works fine on mysql, it creates the tables without any dramas, I was using the following properties with mysql:

```
#spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/users
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
##spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.database: MySql
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
##spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
```

Could it be because I'm using a `Point` data type from vividsolutions?

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
@Column(name = "coords", columnDefinition="Geometry", nullable = true)
private Point location;
```

Do I have todo anything else to allow hibernate to use postgres? I've setup `postgis` on my postgres server as well.

I removed the Point declaration, and it still throws the same errors...So that's not the problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It turns out you cannot have a table named `user` in ***postgres***. So simply changing the table name from ***user*** to ***user_entity*** fixed this.

Comment: @MatheusAraujo I'd say that's the kind of knowledge which is needed in unintuitive software which is always bad software. Experitise can't be the accumulated time wasted for programmers incapacities of writing software that is less intuitive than possible.

Comment: **You can't have columns named user too!**

Comment: @KarlRichter at least in 2020 this doesn't seem to be true.
This works for me without any issues.
```CREATE TABLE if not exists mynamespace.user(id text,  "user" text );
```
Nevertheless, in combination with JPA I am getting the same issue as shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer doesn't seem to be up to date I would like to propose different solution:

Note: I guess you are using JPA and named your Entity User.
Also be aware of the \"

```
@Entity(name = "\"User\"")
public class User implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Btw: The same issue appears for entities named "authorization"

Although this works for current postgres / hibernate versions, I would rather suggest to name the entity user_entity or users.

Answer (score 0):

if you have relational field, just use CascadeType.All:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```